# How to make multiples filters in one describe_[resource] with boto3?

Tags: python, boto3

is possible make something like the example to get one sg from an specific vpc?:

```
sgs = client.describe_security_groups(
    Filters=[
        {'Name': 'vpc-id', 'Values': ['vpc-1111111']},
        {'Name': 'GroupName': 'Values': ['sg_name']}
    ]
)
```

Comment: I think "is possible that support only one parameter Name in filter with multiple values only?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question but if you want to filter the results based on both a `vpc-id` and the name of a group, you would do this:

```
sgs = client.describe_security_groups(
          Filters=[{'Name': 'vpc-id', 'Values': ['vpc-11111111']},
                   {'Name': 'group-name', 'Values': ['sg-name']}])
```

Does that help?

Comment: don't work say: Invalid type for parameter Filters[1].Values, value: sg-name, type: <type 'str'>, valid types: <type 'list'>, <type 'tuple'>

Comment: Autocorrect unhelpfully changed ``vpc_id`` to ``vac_id``.  I have corrected that and tested the above command and it works for me.

Comment: From the error you showed, it sounds like you are passing a string for the ``Values`` part of ``group-name`` rather than a list of strings.